# how to create custom loss function which can slice model input data in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

I am trying to construct a custom loss function that can give me covariance. My input shape to the model input is [batch_size,1,n_features,1] and my output tensor (y_pred) is of size [batch_size, 1]. Here is my loss function:

```
@tf1.function
@tf1.autograph.experimental.do_not_convert
def custom_loss(batch1, input1, input2):
    a = tf.squeeze(input1, axis=1)
    b = tf.squeeze(input2, axis=1)
    c = tf1.dtypes.complex(a,b)
    Ns = 1920

    # shape = a.get_shape()
    def my_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        g = 0
        index_ML = tf.reshape((Ns - y_true), (batch1,1))
        for ii in range(batch1):
            # index_ML = 0
            if y_true[ii, 0] > 0:
                d = a[ii, tf1.cast(index_ML[ii], tf1.int32):]
                index_ML = tf.reshape((Ns - y_pred), (batch1,1))
        # d1 = c[tf1.cast(index_ML, tf1.int32):,]
            elif tf.math.less(y_true[ii, 0], 0):
                index_ML = Ns + y_true[ii, 0]
                d = tf.exp(tf.complex(1, -y_true[ii, 1]))*c[0:-index_ML]
            else:
                d = c

            if tf.math.greater(y_pred[ii, 0], 0):
                index_ML = tf.squeeze(tf1.cast((Ns - y_pred), tf1.int32), axis=1)
                d1 = tf.exp(tf1.complex(1.0, -y_pred))*c[(index_ML):,]
            elif tf.math.less(y_pred[ii, 0], 0):
                index_ML = Ns + y_pred(ii, 0)
                d1 = tf.exp(tf.complex(1, -y_pred[ii, 1]))*c[0:-index_ML]
            else:
                d1 = c

        g = tf.math.add(g, tfp.stats.covariance(d, d1))
        return tf1.squeeze(tf.reduce_sum(g))
```

And also find my model summary as follows:

```
Model: "model_1"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
time_distributed_114_input (Inp [(None, 1, None, 1)] 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_117_input (Inp [(None, 1, None, 1)] 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_114 (TimeDistr (None, 1, None, 256) 16640       time_distributed_114_input[0][0] 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_117 (TimeDistr (None, 1, None, 256) 16640       time_distributed_117_input[0][0] 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_115 (TimeDistr (None, 1, None, 128) 1048704     time_distributed_114[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_118 (TimeDistr (None, 1, None, 128) 1048704     time_distributed_117[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
spatial_pyramid_pooling2d_38 (S (None, 3, 128)       0           time_distributed_115[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
spatial_pyramid_pooling2d_39 (S (None, 3, 128)       0           time_distributed_118[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_116 (TimeDistr (None, 3, 128)       0           spatial_pyramid_pooling2d_38[0][0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_119 (TimeDistr (None, 3, 128)       0           spatial_pyramid_pooling2d_39[0][0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_19 (Concatenate)    (None, 3, 256)       0           time_distributed_116[0][0]       
                                                                 time_distributed_119[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_19 (LSTM)                  (None, 3, 512)       1574912     concatenate_19[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_37 (Dropout)            (None, 3, 512)       0           lstm_19[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
attention_18 (attention)        (None, 512)          515         dropout_37[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_90 (Dense)                (None, 512)          262656      attention_18[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_38 (Dropout)            (None, 512)          0           dense_90[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_72 (BatchNo (None, 512)          2048        dropout_38[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_91 (Dense)                (None, 128)          65664       batch_normalization_72[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_73 (BatchNo (None, 128)          512         dense_91[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_92 (Dense)                (None, 64)           8256        batch_normalization_73[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_74 (BatchNo (None, 64)           256         dense_92[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_93 (Dense)                (None, 16)           1040        batch_normalization_74[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_75 (BatchNo (None, 16)           64          dense_93[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_94 (Dense)                (None, 1)            17          batch_normalization_75[0][0]     
==================================================================================================
Total params: 4,046,628
Trainable params: 4,045,188
Non-trainable params: 1,440
```

I am getting error like: TypeError: in user code:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-4-916657b930aa> in <module>
      2 
      3 tf1.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
----> 4 model1 = toe_foe_est_cnn_lstm_att()
      5 model1.summary()

<ipython-input-3-c2a0abe04543> in toe_foe_est_cnn_lstm_att()
    109     model = keras.Model(inputs=[model_1.input, model_2.input], outputs=[a3])
    110     # model.add_loss(custom_loss(model_1.input, model_2.input))
--> 111     model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss = custom_loss(model_1.input, model_2.input), metrics=['mse'])
    112     # model.summary()
    113     # model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mse'])

e:\mahesh\ofdm\dnn\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    515     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    516     try:
--> 517       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    518     finally:
    519       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

e:\mahesh\ofdm\dnn\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_v1.py in compile(self, optimizer, loss, metrics, loss_weights, sample_weight_mode, weighted_metrics, target_tensors, distribute, **kwargs)
    417     # Prepare list of loss functions, same size of model outputs.
    418     self.loss_functions = training_utils_v1.prepare_loss_functions(
--> 419         self.loss, self.output_names)
    420 
    421     target_tensors = self._process_target_tensor_for_compile(target_tensors)

e:\mahesh\ofdm\dnn\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_utils_v1.py in prepare_loss_functions(loss, output_names)
   1362     loss_functions = nest.map_structure(get_loss_function, loss)
   1363   else:
-> 1364     loss_functions = [get_loss_function(loss) for _ in range(len(output_names))]
   1365 
   1366   return loss_functions

e:\mahesh\ofdm\dnn\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_utils_v1.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1362     loss_functions = nest.map_structure(get_loss_function, loss)
   1363   else:
-> 1364     loss_functions = [get_loss_function(loss) for _ in range(len(output_names))]
   1365 
   1366   return loss_functions

e:\mahesh\ofdm\dnn\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_utils_v1.py in get_loss_function(loss)
   1088   # Wrap loss function with signature `(y_true, y_pred, **kwargs)`
   1089   # in `LossFunctionWrapper` class.
-> 1090   loss_fn = losses.get(loss)
   1091 
   1092   # For losses which are given as strings/functions in the compile API,

e:\mahesh\ofdm\dnn\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py in get(identifier)
   1904   else:
   1905     raise ValueError(
-> 1906         'Could not interpret loss function identifier: {}'.format(identifier))
   1907 
   1908 

ValueError: Could not interpret loss function identifier: name: "PartitionedCall"
op: "PartitionedCall"
input: "time_distributed_input"
input: "time_distributed_3_input"
attr {
  key: "Tin"
  value {
    list {
      type: DT_FLOAT
      type: DT_FLOAT
    }
  }
}
attr {
  key: "Tout"
  value {
    list {
    }
  }
}
attr {
  key: "_collective_manager_ids"
  value {
    list {
    }
  }
}
attr {
  key: "_read_only_resource_inputs"
  value {
    list {
    }
  }
}
attr {
  key: "config"
  value {
    s: ""
  }
}
attr {
  key: "config_proto"
  value {
    s: "\n\007\n\003CPU\020\001\n\007\n\003GPU\020\0012\007 \001*\0010J\0008\001\202\001\000"
  }
}
attr {
  key: "executor_type"
  value {
    s: ""
  }
}
attr {
  key: "f"
  value {
    func {
      name: "__inference_custom_loss_1694"
    }
  }
}
```

I am relatively new to Keras. Kindly help me in this regard.

Comment: Slicing uses brackets [ ] not parenthesis ( ) .

Comment: Did you tried as suggested above?

Comment: Already tried...But it is not working..The problem still persists.